# copy and paste the data one excel to another excel based on column name include blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am just trying to pull the data from one excel to another excel based on column name. Source excel name is "iTerm Export.xls". Sheet name is "export(1)". column heading is "Asset". so when run the below macro Asset column datas has to be copy and paste into the other excel i.e("iTerm metrics Report.xlsx")

But my issue if there is a blank cell anywhere in the Asset column, Ex: there are  50 data rows in Asset column. But 25th and 30 is a blank cell. when i am running the macro once 24 rows copy and paste in the other excel. but i need all fifty rows has to be copy and paste include blank row in other excel

```
Windows("iTerm Export.xls").Activate
Sheets("export(1)").Select
Cells.Find(What:="Asset", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("iTerm metrics Report.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Raw Data from iTerm").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Arul

I won't suggest you to use `.Select` as it is a major cause of errors. See this thread for example

[Run Time Error '1004': Select method of Range Class failed VBA 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916342/run-time-error-1004-select-method-of-range-class-failed-vba-2003/9916480#9916480)

Having said that, I would recommend directly performing the action that you want rather than doing a `.Select` first. Also how are you opening the workbooks "iTerm Export.xls" and "iTerm metrics Report.xlsx"? If they are already opened when you are running the macro then it's ok to use `.Activate` else set a workbook variable and then open the workbooks. That ways you can avoid using `.Activate` as well. Let me know if this is the case and I will provide a sample.

The other drawback of `.Select` and `.Activate` is that it slows down your code drastically.

Your above code can also be written as below. This is the correct way to use `.Find` instead of directly using `.Activate`. The reason being the code will crash on the below line if no match is found.

`Cells.Find(What:="Asset", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= False, _ SearchFormat:=False).Activate`

Hence it is advisable to check if the the value was found and then proceed.

Try this code and see if this is what you want? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range

    Windows("iTerm Export.xls").Activate

    With Sheets("export(1)")
        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Asset", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> Check if "Asset is found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> get the lastrow of the column which has "Asset"
            lastRow = .Range(Split(Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
            .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            Windows("iTerm metrics Report.xlsx").Activate

            .Range( _
            Split(Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & aCell.Row & _
            ":" & _
            Split(Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & lastRow _
            ).Copy _
            Sheets("Raw Data from iTerm").Range("A2")
        Else
            MsgBox "Asset not found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 1):

To get the last row of your column you can do this instead:

```
   lastRow = Selection.EntireColumn.Find(What:="*", after:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).EntireRow.Row 'Use EntireRow to take hidden rows too
```

Then you can:

```
Range(Selection, Cells(lastRow, Selection.Column)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

It stops at a blank because thats what the xlDown selection does.
What I would suggest is selecting the entire column.

```
Columns(4).Select
```

or

```
Columns("D:D").Select
```

or, to get the column that has the active cell

```
Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
```

Comment: sorry all..i have tried above three scnario...but its not matching with my questions...

Answer (score 0):

Sub Create_From_List()

Dim Row As Integer
Row = ActiveCell.Row

```
Dim objList As Worksheet
Set objList = ActiveSheet

Dim wb As Workbook
workingPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

'insert the doc you want to transfer it to (and save it in the same folder as the one the source excel is)

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(workingPath & "\---")
```

' enter cells you copy from the source, then the name of the sheet of the target one and the cells you want to place the info in the target one.

```
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--") 
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--")
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--")
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--")
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--")
CheckAndCopyData objList.Cells(- , -), wb.Sheets("---").Range("--")


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

' you can use the info that you transfer as a name of the doc (use cells of the source doc)

```
wb.SaveAs (workingPath & "\" & objList.Cells(- , -) & " " & objList.Cells(- , -) & 
".xlsx") 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Function CheckAndCopyData(SourceCell As Range, TargetCell As Range)
If Not IsEmpty(SourceCell) Then

TargetCell.Value = SourceCell.Value
End If
End Function
```